# PHP date comparison between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to keep track the status if there is no shipment of product within 2 days then there is must have a notification to alert them by email to do a shipment. The shipment date can be fetch from email date but it is possible if I compare :

```
//MAX(date_shipment = latest date record of shipment in database

if (MAX(date_shipment) - dateNow() >= 2 days )
{
   $update ="update table1 set remarks = 'No shipment received since 2 days ago', status = 'warning'";
   $result = mysql_query($update);
}
else
{ }
```

But there is problem I thinks because this code is compare with `dateNow()`. How come if there is new shipment received, still the date comparison code running but not compare with this new shipment date received. I have no idea how to explain and how to start to do this function.

Can someone advise what is the right way to solve this prob? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us your code. This is not enough for us to go on.

Comment: `if (MAX(date_shipment) - dateNow() >= 2 days )` this won't parse in PHP. Your `update table1 set remarks = 'No shipment received since 2 days ago', status = 'warning'` query will update every row of your table since you didn't specify a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `date_shipment` should be `$date_shipment`? Is this a date element from the database?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I not yet do the code. still in understanding the process flow

Comment: But what if the new shipment is received the status warning is still display right when we just compare the latest date_shipment in db with datenow()

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this code:

```
$currentDate = getdate();
$anotherDate = MAX(date_shipment); //whatever this is

//this will give sql format to the current date
$year = $currentDate['year'];
$month = $currentDate['mon'];
$day = $currentDate['mday'];
$currentDate = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;

$date1 = date_create($anotherDate); //assuming your date has sql format
$date2 = date_create($currentDate);

$difference = date_diff($date1, $date2);
$difference = str_replace(" days","",$difference->format('%R%a days'));

if ($difference >= 2){
    $update ="update table1 set remarks = 'No shipment received since 2 days ago', status = 'warning'";
    $result = mysql_query($update);
}
else
{ } //I don't get what you want here
```

Comment: I got this error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_create()" when I follow this code. Any idea?

Comment: it is like this the function $date=date_create("2013-03-15"); but we have format the date function $currentDate = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;

Comment: It turns out that function date_create() exists. Check here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_create.asp

Answer (score 0):

This seems like what you are trying to do. Do not use mysql anymore, use mysqli.

```
$dbDate = mysql_query("SELECT `date_shipment` FROM table1");

$addedDate = new DateTime();
$addedDate->modify('+2 day');

if ($dbDate['date_shipment'] >= $addedDate)
{
   $update ="UPDATE table1 SET remarks = 'No shipment received since 2 days ago',
   status = 'warning'";
   $result = mysql_query($update);
}
else
{ }
```

Comment: but I'm using mysql now. The program display this error " Call to undefined function mysqli_query()" when I run this code

Comment: I tailored my answer to mysqli, because that is what you should be using. Try it now.

Comment: still there is error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_query()" when Im using mysqli

Comment: You have not updated all your code. Look above, nothing is calling that function. In order to use mysqli, you need to change other code such as the connection.

Comment: $addedDate refer to what? it is current date? because the error display "Fatal error: Class 'DateTime' not found". so i need to update DateTime function. It is possible if I change DateTime() to dateNow()

Comment: You must be using PHP version older than 5.2, my solution won't work for you.